# how to customize css ellipse for a text string

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I have list of title in a drop-down as string ex:

```
"Bharat Untitled offer #564", "Bharat Untitled offer #563"
```

respectively.

Its title is long so, We want title should show first eight character, then '...' and last 4 character.

I used css rules:

```
.title{
    max-width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

And get output like:

> Bharat Unt...

I want out put like:

> Bharat Untitled...ffer

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: CSS wont help you in this case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var charAtBeginning = 10;
var charAtEnd = 7;
var myStr = "I have list of title in a drop-down as string example";
var finalOutput = "";
if (myStr.length > (charAtBeginning + charAtEnd)) {
  finalOutput = myStr.substring(0, charAtBeginning) + '..' + myStr.substring((myStr.length - charAtEnd), myStr.length);
}
alert(finalOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with javascript or jquery then there are certain possible ways to do this thing, i am going to illustrate on menthod here.

```
   function processName(ret){
    ret = ret.substr(0,8) + "..."+ret.substr(ret.length - 5);
    return ret;
   }
```

now All you need to do is to pass each and every value to this function, i assume you know how to do it. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/8ye6df9p/

I made this little thing.. i used a monospace font..  hopes it make you bit wiser..

```css
span {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 6em;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<span>dog eatsdodddddddddgsdfghjkghersdddgsdfghjkghersdddgsdfghjkghersdddgsdfghjkgherstyfghurefyghujrttgyhujrttgyhjretghrtgh</span>

<span>dogfgggyfg ff tgyhujrttgyhjretghrtgh</span>

<span>dog </span>

<span>brainatgs200 </span>
```